# How do I load a chess board into program once saved?

Tags: delphi

I have a procedure that saves a chess board into a text file. I am trying to read the board back in to the program once saved. When I call this procedure I get this error.

[image]

Code which I have for loading in board.

```
Procedure LoadBoard(Var Board : Tboard);
var
  fptr:text;
  i,j,x:integer;
  line:string;
  load:char;

begin
  Write('Do you want a load a game? (Enter Y for yes)');
  Readln(load);
  If (Ord(load) >= 97) and (Ord(load) <= 122)
    Then load := Chr(Ord(load) - 32);

  if load='Y' then
    begin
      assignfile(fptr,'SBoard.txt');
      reset(fptr);
      i:=1;
      repeat
        readln(fptr,line);
        j:=1;
        x:=1;
        repeat
          begin
            if (line[x]<>',') and (line[x+1]<>',')
            then
              begin
                Board[i,j][1]:=line[x];
                Board[i,j][2]:=line[x+1];
              end;
            if line[x]=','
            then
              j:=j+1;
              x:=x+1;
          end;
        until j=9;
        i:=i+1;
      until i=9;
      close(fptr);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your access violation: Google "FEN" for a way positions are often stored. It also contains 50 moves rule information, en passent square, who is to move, ... and all that in one short line of text. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)

Comment: You would save a lot of time when you'd learn how to debug your program instead of asking a question for every single problem you face.

Comment: First question: If you are saving your board state into a text file as multiple strings using `writeln(fptr,Board[i,j])` why are you loading them back into your 2D string array character by character and not directly as strings? For instance `Board[i,j]:=line;`

Comment: Also why aren't you using for loops instead of repeat loops? Since you know exact dimensions of your board I believe you could do this much easier by using for loops instead.

Comment: Also could you please share with us the instructions that were given to you by your teacher? I would really like to see them because I suspect they might be leading you into using of bad programming practices. I especially want to se why my answer in your first question about this isn't good enough because it does cover both loading and saving of the game board even thou it requires different implementation of the game board array.

Comment: Another quick tip. Start naming your variables in more meaningful names. Today you probably still know for what variable x is used but when you will have to take a look at your code after a few months you probably won't have a slightest idea and would have to look at your code to determine that. I myself had to lean this lesson in a hard way. But in my case I had one third of the alphabet :-) So by choosing a more meaningful names for the variables will greatly improve the readability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating things by using a Text file and saving your board line by line.

I think you should use a `TStringList` for saving and loading :

```
Const
  BoardDimension = 8;
  BoardFileName = 'SBoard.txt';

Type
  TBoard = Array [1 .. BoardDimension, 1 .. BoardDimension] Of String;

procedure SaveBoard(Board: TBoard);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  Line, BoardFile: TStringList;
begin
  BoardFile := TStringList.Create;
  Line := TStringList.Create;

  for i := 1 to BoardDimension do
  begin
    Line.Clear;
    for j := 1 to BoardDimension do
      Line.Add(Board[i, j]);
    BoardFile.Add(Line.CommaText);
  end;

  Line.Free;
  BoardFile.SaveToFile(BoardFileName);
  BoardFile.Free;
end;

procedure LoadBoard(Board: TBoard);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  Line, BoardFile: TStringList;
begin
  if not FileExists(BoardFileName) then
    exit; // Show error message

  BoardFile := TStringList.Create;
  BoardFile.LoadFromFile(BoardFileName);

  Line := TStringList.Create;

  for i := 1 to BoardDimension  do
  begin
    Line.CommaText := BoardFile[i];
    for j := 1 to BoardDimension  do
      Board[i, j] := Line[j];
  end;

  Line.Free;
  BoardFile.Free;
end;
```

And if you want to test the load an save proceudre you could do it like this :

```
procedure Test;
var
  Board: TBoard;
  BoardA: TBoard;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  randomize;
  for i := 1 to BoardDimension  do
    for j := 1 to BoardDimension  do
      Board[i, j] := Random(500).ToString;

   SaveBoard(Board); //Save Board
   LoadBoard(BoardA); //Load the file into a NEW board

  for i := 1 to BoardDimension  do //Comapre the two boards
    for j := 1 to BoardDimension  do
      if Board[i,j] <> BoardA[i,j] then
        raise Exception.Create('Wrong file format');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the Access Violation exception because the string *members* in your `Board` array are empty (length is zero) and therefore have no accessible character positions.

To fix your present code, you should use `SetLength()` on each string member before you assign content to the character positions. You have not shown what the strings contain, so only you know what the set length should be.

On the other hand, in previous answer to your questions you have been adviced several other methods to save your chess board. You should review those and possibly choose one of them. It would also be polite to respond to those answers and maybe tell why you did not select them. Maybe we were not able to explain the benefits.